# Why does it not display Exception error

Tags: java

```
      List<String> AccountList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
      AccountList.add("45678690");
      AccountList.add("7878787");
      Scanner AccountInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      int x = 1;
 do{
     try{ 

      System.out.println("Hi whats your pin code?");
      String Value = AccountInput.nextLine();

      for  (int counter = 0; counter < AccountList.size(); counter++){  
          if (AccountList.contains(Value)){ //If Input = ArrayList number then display "hi"
              System.out.println("Hi");

              x = 2;
          }

          }

} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("You cant do that");

}
}while (x==1); 
      }
}
```

When I run this the error "You cant do that" does not appear but it is taken invalid and asks user to re enter number untill valid, how can I get the error line to be displayed?

Comment: Variables names should start with lowercase letter! --- Which statement were you expecting to throw an exception? There is nothing in that code that will throw any exceptions, under normal circumstances (excl. out of memory, closed in stream, ...). --- Also, what is the purpose of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to throw an exception to be able to catch one:

```
for  (int counter = 0; counter < AccountList.size(); counter++){  
    if (AccountList.contains(Value)) { //If Input = ArrayList number then display "hi"
        System.out.println("Hi");
        x = 2;
    } else {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

EDIT: As said in the comment, the for line is not necessary as the algorithm to know if the value is contained in your AccountList is handled by the contains method.